# Sublime 3: How to change font size on Sidebar? - Ubuntu version

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, ubuntu-14.04, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to to change the size of my sidebar in sublime text 3, version for Ubuntu, but i just can't get it working, i read lots of posts about it, they said that i should have something like this:

```
{
    "class": "sidebar_label",
    "color": [0, 0, 0],
    "font.bold": false,
    "font.size": 14
},
```

on my *settings - default*, but nothing like it in there, for example i find there 
*"bold_folder_labels": true* and works like a charm in my *settings - user*, but i try to put here the *"class": "sidebar_label"* with *"font.size"* and not results at all, maybe I'm just doing it wrong, please a little help, the text is so small that i can hardly read it.
Another thing i observed:

- Changing theme doesn't affects the sidebar

I don't remember if this is always true, but i think on my older laptop changing that change the colors of the sidebar and fonts, i remember use it before *soda theme* for getting smaller fonts on a low resolution laptop.

Thanks in advance, *regards*

Comment: what theme are you currently using?

Comment: "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme"

Comment: no, what is your **theme**? It's set using the `"theme"` setting in your preferences. If that isn't set at all, you're using the Default theme. You had mentioned Soda in your comment, and my answer will vary depending on which theme you're using...

Comment: "theme": "Default.sublime-theme", sorry there is it, i try it before with soda theme, but since i don't have any changes i just remove it, is just the default theme, thanks for your time

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will need to edit the `Default.sublime-theme` file to do this, not your preferences. Unfortunately, in Sublime Text 3 this file is contained in a zipped `.sublime-package` file, so you'll need to extract that first. Install the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin via Package Control, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on OS X) and type ***`prv`*** to bring up the **P**ackage**R**esource**V**iewer options. Select `Open Resource`, scroll down to `Theme - Default`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, scroll down to `Default.sublime-theme`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to open it.

Next, search for **`sidebar_label`** and modify the first one (on line 362) to look like this (it needs to be valid JSON):

```js
{
    "class": "sidebar_label",
    "color": [0, 0, 0],
    "font.bold": false,
    "font.italic": false, // <-- add comma
    "font.size": 14 // <-- new line
    // , "shadow_color": [250, 250, 250], "shadow_offset": [0, 0]
},
```

Save the file, and you should see the sidebar font size change. You can change `14` to whatever size you want, depending on your personal preferences.

---

If you want to do this in Sublime Text 2, it's a bit easier, as nothing is zipped up. Select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open up your `Packages` folder in your operating system's file navigator. Enter the `Theme - Default` subdirectory and open `Default.sublime-theme` as a JSON file, then edit it as above.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, works perfect, i just miss understand this before, i really appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Preferences > Setting`
In the right side pane, add this [image: Please See the right side]

```
"font_face": "Courier New",
"font_size": 10
```

Put the necessary `commas(,)` where needed. And it will change the font size. 
Thank you.

Comment: Although it's correct in sense for changing font for editor but it's wrong answer. It can't change SideBar font.